# Mouse cursor is invisible in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, mouse-cursor

I'm designing a first person shooting game in unity. I used FPS controller to control the player. Hence, my mouse cursor remains invisible most of the time and when I press Escape, it becomes visible.

The problem is when I load a new scene from a scene that uses FPS controller, the mouse cursor remains invisible although the new scene does not use FPS controller. Moreover, pressing Escape does not show the mouse cursor in the new scene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deal with that in a few ways, but here is the core of the problem: 
Changing the `Cursor.visible` field is not scene dependent, and it does not get reset when a new scene is loaded. Because of that, you need to set `Cursor.visible = true;` on the level you load.

I would suggest making a simple script like CursorVisibility that would read this:

```
public class CursorVisibility : MonoBehaviour
{
    void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level)
    {
        if (FindObjectOfType<FirstPersonController>() != null)
        {
            Cursor.visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor.visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Place this on an empty game object in every scene and you have cursor visibility handled automatically.

You can also just place the function:

```
void OnLevelWasLoaded(int level)
{
    if (FindObjectOfType<FirstPersonController>() != null)
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Cursor.visible = true;
    }
}
```

in any other script that is unique to the scene without a first person controller.

Just make sure to replace the name of the script with whatever the FPS controller is actually named :)

Comment: Didn't work for me; what did work though, was to add
        `Cursor.visible = true;
        Screen.lockCursor = false;`
to the start handler of a script.

Answer (score 1):

To me the solution was to look for `Cursor.visible` and `Screen.lockCursor` parameter and to set:

```
Cursor.visible = true;
Screen.lockCursor = false;
```

Or simply remove `lockCursor` line.

Answer (score 0):

in the Update() function paste these

Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;

Cursor.visible = true;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).